# AngularJs ng-show/hide button trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, ng-show

My target: Button that show/hide div depending on its ng-repeat checkbox state. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o8Q7RZUflYqlt4qzCyay?p=info)

```
  <button ng-click="toggleIt()">Toggle it</button>
  <p>Check all</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
  <br />
  <p>Checkboxes</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="c in checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[$index].selected">
  <div ng-show="checkbox[0].selected && shownow">Slave one showed!</div>
  <div ng-show="checkbox[1].selected && shownow">Slave two showed!</div>
  <div ng-show="checkbox[2].selected && shownow">Slave three showed!</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkbox = [{
    selected: false
  }, {
    selected: false
  }, {
    selected: false
  }];
  // Check/uncheck all boxes
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function(obj) {
      obj.selected = $scope.selectAll;
      $scope.shownow = false;
    });
  };

  $scope.shownow = false;


  $scope.toggleIt = function() {
    $scope.shownow = true;
  }

  $scope.$watchGroup(['checkbox[0].selected', 'checkbox[1].selected', 'checkbox[2].selected'], function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue) {
      $scope.shownow = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Problem: after I uncheck one of the checkboxes, divs disappears. But it shouldn't...

Comment: divs must be shown after button "toggle it" is pressed!

Comment: divs must be hided after button "toggle it" is pressed!

Comment: if it is too hard, you can vote up the question :)

Comment: It is not hard at all, just we don't get what is your requirement. What do you expect to happen when you change the checkbox when the divs are shown? Should the divs become hidden? Or you only want them to be hidden when you click the button second time?

Comment: when checkbox is checked - nothing must happnes. when "toggle em!" button is hit - it shows/ hide divs, depending on it's ng-model checkbox.

Comment: when divs are shown and checkbox is changed, does the divs update to reflect the new checked items immediately, or they need to wait until the button is clicked twice again (hide + show)?

Comment: Changes are reflected after button is hit: Example u make 10 random clicks on checkboxs and at the and 1st one and 3rd are checkd. Then when you click toggle it button u see the 1st and 3rd div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like

Js File

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkbox = [
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    }
  ];
  // Check/uncheck all boxes
  $scope.checkAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function (obj) {
      obj.selected = $scope.selectAll;
       $scope.shownow = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleIt = function(){
    $scope.shownow = !$scope.shownow;
    $scope.selectAll = ! $scope.selectAll
    $scope.checkAll();
  }

});
```

Html File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <button ng-click="toggleIt()">Toggle it</button>
  <p>Check all</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
  <br />

  <p>Checkboxes</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="c in checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[$index].selected">


  <div ng-show="checkbox[0].selected && shownow">Slave one showed!</div>
  <div ng-show="checkbox[1].selected && shownow">Slave two showed!</div>
  <div ng-show="checkbox[2].selected && shownow">Slave three showed!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please refer to the **updated** fiddle: "http://plnkr.co/edit/7GXqApEjfPkZFsQeLbQM?p=preview"

Comment: Content must be shown after button "toggle it" is pressed.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle if it can answer your query "http://plnkr.co/edit/7GXqApEjfPkZFsQeLbQM?p=preview"

Comment: NO. check first checkbox, press "toggle it". check second checkbox. Result: it shows second div.... When I press checkbox I must NOT see it's div. I must see the div after i check checkbox AND i press the toggle it button

Comment: but as per the above comment after you uncheck one of the checkboxes all div should disappear as it will wait for the toogle button to get clicked. please clarify.

Comment: always wait for toggle.

Comment: Then there is no problem in your code !! Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Just update it with `||`

```
<div ng-show="checkbox[0].selected || shownow">Slave one showed!</div>
<div ng-show="checkbox[1].selected || shownow">Slave two showed!</div>
<div ng-show="checkbox[2].selected || shownow">Slave three showed!</div>
```

i've updated your plunker. Please check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cxJshRGDen7t35nEYlB?p=preview)

Comment: I want to see the divs after button toggle is hit

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the method as following :

```
$scope.toggleIt = function(){
    $scope.shownow = !$scope.shownow;
  }
```

And you can do away with adding the watcher also.

This should work (pretty clean way of doing it). Please refer the plnkr

UPDATE PLNKR :

http://plnkr.co/edit/WN9ohx?p=preview

Comment: divs must be shown after button "toggle it" is pressed!

Comment: So there has to be a '||' (OR) condition instead of '&&'(AND) in your HTML. Please look at the updated plnkr. If this is what you need.

Comment: do you understand, that when I press checkbox I must NOT see it's div. I must see the div after i check checkbox AND i press the toggle it button.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically created a watch for the checkboxes and hide the divs when any change happens, but you call it a problem...

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['checkbox[0].selected', 'checkbox[1].selected', 'checkbox[2].selected'], function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue) {
      $scope.shownow = false;
    }
});
```

Is removing this part achieving what you want?

Comment: divs must be shown after button "toggle it" is pressed!

Answer (score 0):

Answer per clarified requirement in the comments of original post:

Angular model binding works in real time: when you click a checkbox, it always reflect the changes immediately. To delay the update until the next click of button, you can store the displayed result in other variable, and update it when you need the change.

```
$scope.showDivs = $scope.checkbox.map(function(item){
  return item.selected;
});

<div ng-show="showDivs[0]">Slave one showed!</div>
<div ng-show="showDivs[1]">Slave two showed!</div>
<div ng-show="showDivs[2]">Slave three showed!</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AlCcytkfZThSElMlMEfb?p=preview)